# Show 5 most recent actions, delete rest?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a button that posts an 'act' into a database.

Act_name, act_date, act_data

basically I order them like this:

```
$this->select - $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM acts ORDER BY date DESC");
```

This shows most 5 recent actions.

How can I delete rest action in that same database table? for example, we have 5 acts, I just posted a new act, the 5th act act becomes 6th, and gets deleted right away?.

Comment: Do you mean delete as in removing it from your database or just not having it returned in the SELECT query?

Comment: Removing completely, using DELETE FROM